# Deserialize JSON and assign to model

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

As part of my web api, I'm getting the following JSON returned.

```
["{\"InputType\":17,\"EngineSubType\":4,\"Filename\":\"targetFile.csv\",\"FileExtensionType\":\".csv\",\"IsLoadFile\":true,\"LoadContextId\":4121,\"ReportingDate\":\"2019-05-31T00:00:00\",\"IsSuccess\":false}"]
```

What I'm wanting to do is grab the value next to `Filename`and assign it to my models `Filename` parameter.

In my project I've created a unit test to experiment with grabbing that value, but each attempt I've making is failing.

In my test I have following DTO Model:

```
public class HangfireTestDTO
{
    public string InputType { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Then my text logic is this:

```
[Fact]
public void TestDTO()
{
    string data =
          "[\"{\\\"InputType\\\":12,\\\"EngineSubType\\\":2,\\\"Filename\\\":\\\"targetFile.csv\\\",\\\"FileExtensionType\\\":\\\".csv\\\",\\\"IsLoadFile\\\":true,\\\"LoadContextId\\\":4120,\\\"ReportingDate\\\":\\\"2019-05-31T00:00:00\\\",\\\"IsSuccess\\\":false}\"]";

     // fails here
     var arguments = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HangfireTestDTO>(data);

     // This is wrong - ignore for now
     Assert.Equal("targetFile.csv", arguments.ToString());

}
```

When I debug the above in my test it tells me the following:

> The JSON value could not be converted to MyProject.HangfireTestDTO

My thinking then led me to try again by modifying the deserialize line to the following:

```
 var arguments = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<HangfireTestDTO>>(data).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when running it with the new line, I get the following error:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like JSON in JSON. Try to parse a list of strings, and parse those strings individually.

Comment: whatever generated your JSON should be restructured ASAP. nested JSON is basically always a sign of badly designed code, and always potential trouble in the future.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann that's hangfire. Zero control over that

Comment: You've accepted an answer that wouldn't work with the JSON you presented in your question - does that mean your JSON isn't *actually* like that?

Comment: @N0xus then tell whoever's responsible to fix their code, and don't stop telling them until they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is because of `InputType`. It should be `int`

```
public class HangfireTestDTO
{
    public int InputType { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

The second error is because of `JSON`. There is an addition quotation between `[` and `{`. I have tried with below `JSON` and it worked. Because of this quotation it becomes `List<string>` and not `List<HangfireTestDTO>`

```
[
    {
        "InputType": 12,
        "EngineSubType": 2,
        "Filename": "targetFile.csv",
        "FileExtensionType": ".csv",
        "IsLoadFile": true,
        "LoadContextId": 4120,
        "ReportingDate": "2019-05-31T00:00:00",
        "IsSuccess": false
    }
]
```

And looking at the `JSON` it should be `IEnumerable<HangfireTestDTO>`

```
var arguments = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<HangfireTestDTO>>(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but it generates the same error I mentioned above `The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1`

Comment: @N0xus, unfortunately your json is not in the correct format. There is an addition quote causing the issue `[\"{`.

Answer (score 1):

firstly your JSON is wrong 
i would expect it too look more like

```
string data = @"[{""InputType"":12,""EngineSubType"":2,""Filename"":""targetFile.csv"",""FileExtensionType"":"".csv"",""IsLoadFile"":true,""LoadContextId"":4120,""ReportingDate"":""2019-05-31T00:00:00"",""IsSuccess"":false}]"
```

or

```
string data = "[{\"InputType\":17,\"EngineSubType\":4,\"Filename\":\"targetFile.csv\",\"FileExtensionType\":\".csv\",\"IsLoadFile\":true,\"LoadContextId\":4121,\"ReportingDate\":\"2019-05-31T00:00:00\",\"IsSuccess\":false}]"
```

second you have wrapped your JSON in [] this means a list of docs so `Deserialize<HangfireTestDTO>(data);` would be `Deserialize<List<HangfireTestDTO>>(data);` or some other IEnumerable

then you have serveral data mismatches 12 is a number not a string so InputType should be an int or double, IsSuccess is a bool, etc

finally you have lots of fields in your JSON that aren't on your object you need to explain to c# what to do with them either create the extra properties or provide a KeyValue store it can put them in 
ie

```
[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string, object> ExtensionData { get; set; }
```

EDIT following the comment you made if that is really how the data is coming out your DB then its an array of strings where the strings are JSON encoded

in which case you will need to read the strings then parse them after

```
var jsonlist = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(data);
foreach(string json in jsonlist )
    var dto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HangfireTestDTO>(json);
```

Comment: The JSON is taken straight from my hangfire database. When you enqueue a job, that is what it generates. Zero control over that.

Comment: no you've changed it when you created your data variable for your test, lots of extra \'s for one thing

Answer (score 1):

Your current JSON string is an array of strings. You need to first deserialize the JSON *into* a list of strings, then deserialize each of those strings as a DTO. Here's a complete example using your JSON:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

public class HangfireTestDTO
{
    public int InputType { get; set; }
    public int EngineSubType { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string FileExtensionType { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string data =
          "[\"{\\\"InputType\\\":12,\\\"EngineSubType\\\":2,\\\"Filename\\\":\\\"targetFile.csv\\\",\\\"FileExtensionType\\\":\\\".csv\\\",\\\"IsLoadFile\\\":true,\\\"LoadContextId\\\":4120,\\\"ReportingDate\\\":\\\"2019-05-31T00:00:00\\\",\\\"IsSuccess\\\":false}\"]";

        // First deserialize the single string to a list of strings
        List<string> jsonStrings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(data);

        // Then deserialize each of the strings to a DTO.
        List<HangfireTestDTO> dtos = jsonStrings
            .Select(json => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HangfireTestDTO>(json))
            .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(dtos.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(dtos[0].Filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems, that OP is using `System.Text.Json`, not the `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Ah, will fix. It's likely to be almost identical code though.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Done :)