# Parsing JSON response from StreamBuilder C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I'm getting a JSON response back from another website and then building the response from a StreamReader:-

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
            response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The result I'm getting is:-

```
string response = "{\"d\":\"[{\\\"Animal\\\":\\\"Cat\\\",\\\"Noise\\\":\\\"Meow\\\"},{\\\"Animal\\\":\\\"Dog\\\",\\\"Noise\\\":\\\"Woof\\\"}]\"}";
```

I've then used the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response) to deserialise and then I'm then trying to loop through the results to read the values.. but it's not working whatever I try

```
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
var arr = jObj; //Tried var arr = jObj.d;

@foreach (var item in arr)
{
 ….
}
```

**Error**: *Target type System.Collections.IEnumerable is not a value type or a non-abstract class.
Parameter name: targetType*

Comment: `d` actually has an array as content, wrapped into string

Comment: It seems that a JSON data becomes a value for a key in the main JSON

Comment: What API are you querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response contains a `d` property, which value is an array wrapped into string itself.

So, you should parse a `d` content separately into array, `Json.Linq` solution is below

```cs
string response = "{\"d\":\"[{\\\"Animal\\\":\\\"Cat\\\",\\\"Noise\\\":\\\"Meow\\\"},{\\\"Animal\\\":\\\"Dog\\\",\\\"Noise\\\":\\\"Woof\\\"}]\"}";
var json = JObject.Parse(response);
var array = json["d"];

foreach (var item in JArray.Parse(array.ToString()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Animal"]);
}
```

Solution with deserialization to `dynamic` object

```cs
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
var array = json?.d;

foreach (var item in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(array?.ToString()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item?.Animal);
}
```

It allows you to parse the response without any changes to source JSON

Comment: Do you suppose there's any useful purpose in the API authors wrapping the array in a string and forcing the extra deserialization step?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Personally, I didn't see any valid reasons for that:) I guess, that OP doesn't have a control over this API, he can ask API authors for specification and reasons. I've already seen the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397175/deserialize-json-and-assign-to-model) few days ago, response was taken from hangfire, maybe OP has the same API contract

Answer (score 0):

If you printed `response`, you would see that `jObj.d` is not an array, but a string.  In fact, it looks like the string representation of an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "d"'s value contains another JSON data. If it is correct and you don't want to touch the JSON format, here is the solution:

```
    string response = "{\"d\":\"[{\\\"Animal\\\":\\\"Cat\\\",\\\"Noise\\\":\\\"Meow\\\"},{\\\"Animal\\\":\\\"Dog\\\",\\\"Noise\\\":\\\"Woof\\\"}]\"}";

    dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

    var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<D[]>((jObj.d).Value);

    foreach (var item in arr)
    {

    }

     ........

    public class D
    {
        public string Animal { get; set; }
        public string Noise { get; set; }
    }
```